# When to use Wa'iyyak vs Wa'iyyakum?

Tags: arabic

What is the difference between the two and when should they be used?

Also when addressing one person what is the difference between Jazakallah Khayrun vs Jazakallah Khair?

Comment: Welcome to IslamSE , why don't you try an arabic dictionary ?

Comment: Jazaka Allahu Khayrun is not (correct) Arabic and Jazaka Allahu Khayr is a lazy form which ignores the correct rulings of grammar which could also be regarded as incorrect. People using it either are in doubt of the grammar or lazy.

Comment: @Medi1Saif what will be correct arabic in that case? Can you see the accepted answer, he linked a Hadith which talks about using Jazkallah Khayrun

Comment: @user15296915 https://sunnah.com/search?q=Jazak-Allah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. When using Wa-iyyak or Wa-iyyakum it depends who you are addressing. In arabic there are pronouns that are attached and de-attached. In this case these are attached pronouns.

1 male - wa-iyyaka 
2 males - wa-iyyakuma 
3 or more males - wa-iyyakum

1 female - wa-iyyaki (kee) 
2 females - wa-iyyakuma 
3 or more females - wa-iyyakuna

[image]

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eo8PC62VhNM&ab_channel=AlhudaDiaries

**Regarding your second question:**

> The Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) said, “He who is favoured by another and says to his benefactor: `**Jazak-Allah khairan** (may Allah reward you well)’ indeed praised (the benefactor) satisfactorily.” Riyad As-Salihin – [At-Tirmidhi]

Comment: Jazakallah Khairan! What about when addressing a mix crowd of male and female?

Comment: @user15296915 as in most other languages in case that at least one male is within a group the grammar used is for male plural.